# Extract only version portion of a package name with bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, rpm, version

I would like to extract from a package name only the version of the package. Assuming I have a variable `var` that contains a package name (E.g.: `var="nfs-utils-1.2.6-6.fc17.i686.rpm"` ). The string extracted would be `1.2.6-6`. The method used to parse can be anything (regex, awk, cut).

Edit:
In the example above  I would actually like to extract `1.2.6`

Comment: `rpm --queryformat ...` would be a far superior way rather than reinventing RPM version string parsing.

Comment: in your example, "1.2.6" is the version, while "6.fc17" is the release; are you actually trying to get the (rpm) %VERSION, or do you actually want to include the first piece of the %RELEASE? see: `rpm -qa --queryformat="%{NAME} %{VERSION} %{RELEASE}\n"`

Comment: I was not aware that the 6 after the hifen was part of the release. Thanks for clarifying this. All I care for is the version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not very portable, but for this specific case, this `grep` works:

```
echo $var | egrep -o '[0-9].*-[0-9]'
1.2.6-6
```

Comment: By not very portable you mean between different linux distros? I am using it exclusively on FC 17 and FC 22

Comment: egrep can be installed in every linux distros (except the no-gnu distros, like android). I think he is talking about other unix systems ;-)

Comment: No, I mean that it will not work on a different package name; for instance if the version is `1.2.33` this `grep` will not work.

Answer (score 5):

As thrig said, *if* you're extracting the values on the same system where those packages are installed, you can ask RPM for the version directly:

```
ver=$(rpm --queryformat="%{VERSION}" -q nfs-utils)
```

Comment: Thats nice! I liked it.

Comment: I am trying to compare the version of a package saved in a folder with the version of the packages currently installed. If they differ, I attempt to install the package saved in the folder.

Comment: then grab the other version with `ver2=$(rpm --queryformat="%{VERSION}" -qp /path/to/saved/folder/package.rpm`

Answer (score 0):

The last 2 '-' characters surround the version.

So one can write a *RE that is anchored at the end of the string with a '$'

E.g.

```
$ echo nfs-utils-1.2.6-6.fc17.i686.rpm | sed -e 's,.*-\([^-]*\)-[^-]*$,\1,'
```

1.2.6

Comment: $ echo nfs-utils-1.2.6-6.fc17.i686.rpm | sed -e 's,.*-\([^-]*-[^-]*\).i686.rpm$,\1,'
1.2.6-6.fc17